# Как определить индекс используемой вкладки в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

У меня есть несколько вкладок :

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

note=ttk.Notebook(root)
note.pack(side=TOP,fill=X)

f1=Frame(note,height=400)
f2=Frame(note,height=400)

note.add(f1,text="tab 1")
note.add(f2,text="tab 2")

def find():
    # код для отслеживания используемой вкладки

bar=Button(root,text="some text",bg="light grey", command=find)
bar.pack(side=TOP,fill=X)

root.mainloop()
```

Вот результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И при нажатии на кнопку мне нужно вывести индекс используемой вкладки.
Можете подсказать как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def find():
    print(note.tabs().index(note.select()))
```

Метод `note.select()` возвращает текущую вкладку как объект (или меняет текущую вкладку, если передать в этот метод индекс нужной вкладки), `note.tabs()` возвращает список всех вкладок. Дальше с помощью метода `index` списка находим индекс текущей вкладки.